# iCloud for each Mac Profile

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air setup with two profiles that I want to hook up to iCloud.  Is there any way to point each profile to a different iCloud account?  If so, can I share files between accounts?  And, if not, what is the best approach to take to keep the content of each profile separate on iCloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not. They are completely different users and so on a multiuser system, each account would have its own settings and the information would persist in the keychain of that user.

Comment: You could improve your answer by stating exactly how to achieve this.